# How can I make my brand new module dependent on a minimal core version that's required for it to work OK?

Tags: hooks

I am developing a brand new module (there isn't any site using it yet). It requires a specific Drupal version, as it uses the [`hook_taxonomy_term_view()` hook that was introduced in Drupal core version 7.17](http://drupal.org/node/1808870).

I want to avoid my module being enabled on a site using, for example, Drupal 7.16 or any earlier versions of Drupal core. Higher versions of Drupal, above 7.17, should be fine.

**My Question**: How can I make my module dependent on that Drupal 7.17 version, which is a minimum for my module?

Note: I don't need (have to worry about) a solution for sites where the module is already installed. So there is no need for it to be disabled somehow in such pre-7.17 Drupal versions.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:hooks] because it is about a hook I should use in my code. [tag:hooks] doesn't mean I am looking for a hook I could use; I am open to any solution that allows me to avoid the module is installed on a site not using Drupal 7.17, or higher.

Comment: You can require a minor version of some other module by `dependencies[] = mymodule (1.12)` but it seems like this doesn't work for core.

Comment: @AyeshK Uh! Now, that could be interesting, if you could point me to a Drupal core module that is always enabled.

Comment: I tried it with `dependencies[] = taxonomy (>7.17)` and some other possible version numbers but didn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The trick, apparently, is to add the System module as dependency for the module.

```
dependencies[] = system (>=7.17)
```

Comment: Yes, the trick is that. Given that the System module is always installed from Drupal, requiring it won't cause users to first install an optional module that isn't used from the module I am writing, as it would happen with `dependencies[] = taxonomy (>7.17)`.

Answer (score 7):

[`hook_requirements()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_requirements/7) exists for exactly that sort of purpose.

> Check installation requirements and do status reporting.

You can check the `$phase` parameter to determine if the module is being installed, check the current Drupal version against your required version, and return a severity of [`REQUIREMENT_ERROR`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21install.inc/constant/REQUIREMENT_ERROR/7). That will prevent the module from being installed until the requirement is met.

The documentation is pretty thorough, the one thing worth mentioning here is that the hook needs to be implemented in the module's .install file.

Comment: @chx I'll take your word for it, but in that case the description of the function _"Check installation requirements and do status reporting."_ is somewhat misleading is it not? We are after all talking specifically about checking for module requirements upon installation :)

Comment: I always thought `hook_requirements` was meant for libraries etc. :-\

Comment: @Chapabu Not according to the docs :) It talks about modules specifically, and basically says to use that hook to return `REQUIREMENT_ERROR` to make sure a module is not installed if it fails the requirements. I'd assumed checking the version of Drupal was a valid use case (the docs don't mention _not_ doing that) but I guess I've missed something. It might just be bad practice or something I dunno

Comment: @Clive Weird, dunno where I got that from then..maybe D8 should just be a docs upgrade ;-)

Comment: @Clive Just found this useful page [Contributor task: Backport a Drupal Core patch](http://drupal.org/node/1538380) - "*...if Drupal 8 is in progress, any bugs found in Drupal 6 or 7 need to be fixed first in Drupal 8, and then back-ported to Drupal 7*"

Comment: @Clive The [Backport policy](http://drupal.org/node/767608). seems pretty useful too!

Comment: Thanks @Chapabu I'd seen it but I wasn't sure if it applied to documentation. Coming from a C# background this open source stuff is pretty alien to me ;)

Comment: @Clive I looked into C# once.....looked right back away again ;-)

Comment: @Chapabu I miss it every day...;)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [hook_enabled](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_enable/7)

This would fire after the module is installed. You can check the version of the drupal installed and if it is not the correct version then use [module_disable](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_disable/7) and give the required error message.

Answer (score 0):

With Drupal 8.x, it's still possible to add the System module as dependency of a module, to require a specific Drupal core version. Drupal 8.x uses YAML for the .info file (which now has a .info.yml extension), so the dependencies are declared with code similar to the following one.

```yaml
dependencies:
  - drupal:serialization
  - drupal:system (>=8.2.x)
```

Since Drupal 8.8.0, it's possible to require a more specific Drupal core version using `core_version_requirement`.

```yaml
core_version_requirement: ^8.8 || ^9
```

Using that line, which cannot be used together a line that sets `core`, the module is requiring at least Drupal 8.8.x or Drupal 9.x; any different Drupal version would mark the module as not compatible with the Drupal version used from the site.

As side note, the dependencies in Drupal 8 are namespaced. They require first the project machine name (for example, *drupal* for Drupal core) and then the module machine name (for example, *system* for the System module), separated from a colon. In this way, there isn't any ambiguity on which module is required.

#### Reference

- [Let Drupal know about your module with an .info.yml file](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/let-drupal-know-about-your-module-with-an-infoyml-file)